# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 compatibility on windows server 2016

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, windows-server-2016

is SharePoint Foundation 2013 supported on windows server 2016?

Answer (score 2):

`At this time, Windows Server 2016 RTM is not supported`.read more here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-0

Max you can go win 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. SharePoint Foundation 2013 with Service Pack 1 is compatible up to Windows Server 2012 R2.